# Why are my reputation points reduced every day without showing any message?

Tags: support, reputation

For the last two weeks my reputation points has been reduced by day by day (small amounts max 11) without showing any message (so I think only the top level users can help me because I don't have any proof). Initially I thought it was just my assumption, but after that the problem still exists.

> The most amazing feature is there is no change is showing on daily reputation but
>   on total reputation points.

**How this affects me:** Since I didn't get the correct reason for this reputation points change, I'm not able to understand my mistakes, and I can't improve it next time.

Comment: Do you have the checkbox next to "show removed posts" at the bottom of your reputation history checked?

Comment: You sure it's 2 weeks and not 2 months? You don't happen to remember receiving any emails from moderators during that time?

Comment: @BoltClock i'm not sure  about it.but for a long time i have losing drop by drop,yesterday my total reputation change is -4 but only showing the reason for -2.

Comment: @animuson you are correct bro,I'm ticked and now it's fine.every one vote for close.

Answer (score 16):

I just checked your [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6677244/dream-hunter?tab=reputation). You have had a net loss of reputation on several days due to [removed users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed). This is not your fault. As per the help center, user removal happens when "a user who voted for one of your posts had their account deleted (either by request or due to violating the network's terms of service). As a result, all of their votes were removed, and the reputation you gained or lost from them was undone."

You have lost quite a bit of rep due to user removal in the last month - over 100 rep.

Comment: that is not my doubt,that is a shown change on my reputation page,i"m here discussing about the reputation changes without showing any message.that is why I mentioned that only the top level user's can help me